# How do you debug url routing in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a Flask website using Visual Studio 2013's PythonTools, which has its own debugger, and that allows me to step through the initial setup code, up until `app.run()`

However the code I want to debug is the routing code, like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def url_index():
     return render_template('index.html')
```

I know that function is running because the server does respond with index.html, but if I put a breakpoint on the last line, it'll never get hit.

Is there any way to debug these routing functions? Flask says it comes with a debugger but how do I use it? Will it be compatible with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

For the Flask debugger, you can set `app.debug` to `True`:

```
app.debug = True
```

or

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

And then:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   raise
   return render_template('index.html')
```

And then you can debug the function with the Flask debugger  in your browser.

Comment: That gives me the Flask debug window, which lets me execute python code in that stack frame, but I can't step through the code, and it doesn't interact with the Visual Studio debugger either

Comment: If you want to step thtought the code, you can use `pdb` or `ipdb`, and then put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the code you want to step through.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that, but it would still be nice to be able to interact with the VS debugger instead of manually calling pdb

Comment: Did you installed Python tools for Visual Studio? https://pytools.codeplex.com/ Python debugging is not built-in VS.

Comment: It seems like VS won't debug Flask projects though, even with PTVS.

Answer (score 4):

6 months later, and while it still doesn't look possible to automatically debug URL routing in flask, you can manually attach a debugger to the flask process, though you'll have to re-add it if you restart the server or if the auto-reloader detects changes in your .py files and restarts.

Just go:
`Tools -> Attach to Process`
and select the Python.exe that is ***not*** greyed out (that's the initial flask code that visual studio is already debugging), and then do something that would cause the breakpoint to be hit (e.g. reload the page), and you should have success.

Comment: Can you tell more about how you end up with two processes in the first place? I just tried this using the Flask Web App project template that ships with PTVS 2.1, and breakpoint inside `def home` is hit just fine - and it's all in one process. Can you compare your startup code with the one in `runserver.py` in the template?

Comment: Ah I think I found a clue. If you start the server in [Debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode), which I think most people will be doing, running the server spawns 2 processes and so doesn't hit the breakpoints. If you leave Debug as False (the default), running the sever only makes one python process and the breakpoints are hit. Could you try the debug mode on your machine?

Comment: Ah, I see now. IIRC, the debug mode enables the code reload feature, which is there so that any changes that you make to your code are automatically reloaded in the server process, and this causes grief with PTVS because it doesn't support automatically attaching to child processes spawned by the main one. Feel free to file a feature request for this in the tracker.

Comment: I added it as an [issue in the CodePlex site](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2651) a while back. Is that what you mean by a feature request?

Comment: Yes (I keep forgetting that users can't designate them as "Feature" or "Issue", only maintainers can edit that). I've seen that one, but right now it's basically a narrow "this particular thing doesn't work" issue. The root cause here though is a missing feature - automatically attaching to spawned child process - not a bug. 

I filed it as https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2668, but you should still upvote that :)

Comment: Seems the problem still exists with the latest PTVS for 2015. This solution is still working.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the current version of PTVS doesn't support Flask projects.

Good thing is: the already released PTVS 2.1 alpha does: http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flask

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off reloading with debug mode by using

`app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)`

The [Flask error handling docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/errorhandling/) go into the details of the debugging options.